# Old project on new PC: bad allocation when opening

Tags: qgis, migration

Just got a new laptop (windows7). When opening a QGIS project (shape layers on server), I get an error window "bad allocation. 
Project was made in Wroclaw, new PC has Lisboa.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new simple project, load a shape from the server, save it, and compare the .qgs-Files with the old ones with a good text editor, e.g. notepad++. If you found the difference in < datasource >, you can edit the qgs-files with notepad++. It can open several files at once, and do search&replace on all opened files.

Comment: thanks. What i find is very weird: the directory structure in the old file (wroclav version) has a syntax with "/". n the new file (Lisboa version), it is with "\". as in <datasource>V:\02.DEVELOPMENT\B_CaPa.shp</datasou‌​rce>.  furthermore, the old wroclav code contains "../.." which is of course not a good idea when migrating to another computer.

Comment: Thats the difference between absolute and relative paths. You can change that in project properties, first tab. But ../.. for relative paths comes also here in my Lisboa files. Infact its better to use relative paths if the files are on another drive on the new pc.

Answer (score 2):

When I formated my PC and reinstall Windows and QGIS I had the same message Exception: bad allocation,

After some time I realised the reason for this is that the project I was trying to open contained a google physical map and I hadn't install the open layers plugin.

So maybe if this happens is because a missing plugin.

Diego.